# How to rotate the axis labels in Google image chart

Tags: charts

I want to rotate x axis labels according to attached screenshot, But i am not finding any solution in google image chart.

Also how to put the label on top of the y axis, see the attached screenshot.

[This screenshot the x axis labels rotate in approx 60 deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9bKS.png)

[In this Image the x axis labels appears in vertical format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWKrL.png)

How to put the query for axis rotation in 
chart.apis.google.com/chart link

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please elaborate on your efforts in order to help us help you.

Comment: In google chart api, i don't find to pass the axis rotation parameter http://chart.apis.google.com/chart